# :nth-of-type not targeting desired elements

Tags: css

I'm building a calendar where there are several children inside the .cal-contents container. Like this:

```
<div class="cal-contents">
    <div class="single-day"></div>
    <div class="tooltip"></div>
    <div class="single-day"></div>
    <div class="tooltip"></div>
</div>
```

In this case .single-day and .tooltip follow each other and I'm trying to target every nth .single-day element and style the tooltip after it:

```
.cal-contents .single-day:nth-of-type(1) + .tooltip {
   color: red;
}
.cal-contents .single-day:nth-of-type(2) + .tooltip {
   color: red;
}
```

In the case I'm making, there are only 4 elements with the class: 'single-day' and 4 with 'tooltip'. Trying to play around in the codepen to see if I can get results, but the browser does not properly select them by number 1,2,3 or 4.

Codepen: http://codepen.io/Malachute/pen/dXOPyj?editors=1100

Comment: Pseudo-classes like `:nth-of-type` select elements, not classes. Using a class acts like a filter, making it more restrictive and only selecting an element if it has the class -- it doesn't select an element *with* the class.

Comment: Are you expecting to target the second element with the class name `single-day`? The `:nth-of-type` pseudo selector doesn't target by class name, it targets by source order.